# Integral bound from Steven Orey article

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral, upper-lower-bounds

I am trying to show that
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2/2}(x^2+s)^{-\beta}\, dx\leq 4s^{\frac12-\beta}
$$
for $\beta>1/2$ and $s>0$. It appears in this article:

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00534922,

page 250.

A simple attempt goes like this:
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2/2}(x^2+s)^{-\beta}\, dx\leq s^{\frac12-\beta}\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2/2}(x^2+s)^{-\frac12}\, dx.
$$
I don't believe the integral on the right converges for small enough $s$, so the bound must be tighter. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For what it's worth, we can evaluate the integral in terms Tricomi's $U$ confluent hypergeometric function. $$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^2/2} (x^2+s)^{-\beta} \, dx = 2^{-\beta-1/2} \sqrt{\pi} \, U\left(\beta,\frac{1}{2}+\beta,\frac{s}{2}\right)$$. One can then likely bound this hypergeometric function.

Comment: This is equivalent to $\int_0^\infty e^{-sx^2/2}/(x^2+1)^\beta dx \le 4$.

Comment: This statement appears to be false, though $s$ must be very small for it to be so ($s < 1/660$ is necessary but not sufficient). Additionally, all $\beta > 0.65$ satisfy the condition regardless of $s$.

Comment: @KStarGamer The standard transform on hypergeometric functions gives $ s^{1/2-\beta}(\sqrt{\pi}/2)U(1/2,3/2-\beta,s/2)$, which is more directly relevant to the inequality.